Hibernate with Oracle and database-links
For a monitoring solution, I need to connect to a oracle database, that has multiple database links. For simplifiaction I call them master and nodes.
In Oracle, you can define a database-link within a database, which lets you connect to a different database, a select to a different database is marked with the @ symbol for example:
SELECT * from users; //local instance
SELECT * from users@db_link_name1 // remote db

Since this is dynamic, meaning on each master db there can be several db links, I'm experiencing problems with hibernate
In hibernate (java), I would map the table users to Users.class. It is always the same table schematic in all remote databases. While looking for solutions, its mostly recommended using a synonym, but it my case this is not a working solution, because the class is always the same, so using a synonym as table name is not working. I need a way to select via the DB-link and then always map to the same class.
How can DB Links used in hibernate?

You can simply create synonyms in the database and reference the synonym names from your client code. But perhaps you can be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish and what problem you're having.

Synonyms are only an option when having a fixed, known set of db_links. In my case, I would need a solution that can be iterated, for example one site might have 5 links, another 7 or just one. The db_link amount and name will need to be dynamically changeable

it isn't clear what your requirement actually is. What do you mean by "one site might have 5 links, another 7 or just one" ? Could you update your question with some pseudo-code? If all you need to do is replace a dblink in a query with a different one, then simply do so. What's the problem?

You could create VIEWs for tables @remote db and map Hibernate entities on the views.
